# htaccess not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess

i have

```
www.mydomain.com/page_articles
```

with links that would point to

```
www.mydomain.com/page_articles/some_article
```

but "some_article" get rendered from a php file "load.php" so it would look like:

```
www.mydomain.com/page_articles/load.php?page=some_article
```

What would i put in htaccess so that i can have pretty links?

I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page_articles$ /page_articles/load.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^page_articles/$ page_articles/load.php?page=$1
```

THanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^page_articles/(.*)$ page_articles/load.php?page=$1
</IfModule>
```

Adding the brackets in the string allows you to use "some _articles" it the page variable $1, this is assuming there is a file called load.php in the page_articles folder

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work. The (.*) captures whatever comes after the / into $1. .* = any character 0 or more times. The RewriteCond is telling the RewriteRule ignore it if it the match starts with load.php (to avoid an infinite loop). The question mark indicates that there may or may not be a trailing /.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^load\.php
RewriteRule ^page_articles/?(.*) /page_articles/load.php?page=$1 [T=application/x-httpd-php,L,NC]
```